# How to call a function after selecting an option from a select element in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a couple of options in a `<select>` element. How can I call a function when I choose an option?

Here is what I have so far in terms of the JS:

```
export default {
  name: 'Dropdown',
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      logout();
    },
  },
  computed: {
    logout() {
      console.log('logout);
    },
  },
};
```

My select menu looks like this: `<select @change="onChange">...`

When I select an option, I receive the following error: `logout is not defined`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use this to reference the instance, so it will be `this.logout();`

**EDIT:**

You need to create an onLogout in the methods property if you want to do something particular, a computed property is a reactive property that return something, it isn't really meant to do something that handle the logout.

As i see your logout computed property would be more about getting the current status of the user if he's logout or not, but it would be better to rename it.

So if you want to do something particular when the select change(like a logout method)

you need to adapt your component this way:

```
export default {
  name: 'Dropdown',
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      this.logout();
    },
    logout() {
     console.log('logout called');
    },
  },
  computed: {
    userStatus() {
    // return a state or something, but must return something
    return ...
    },
  },
};
```

I invite you to read this documentation to have better idea about computed property and methods

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties
https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html

Answer (score 0):

The logout function should be on the methods object top and you reference it using this.logout()